# Apache ab will not work - ab: invalid URL when testing python cyclone

Tags: nginx, apachebench, cyclone

I am trying to ab test cyclone.

When I run

```
ab -n 2000 -c 25 http://127.0.0.1
```

I get ab: invalid URL.

Well...when I go to ff on my dev machine, the site is there.

Here is my nginx config

```
http {

    upstream frontends {
        server 127.0.0.1:8051;
    }

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 30;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;
    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

        # Only retry if there was a communication error, not a timeout
        # on the Tornado server (to avoid propagating "queries of death"
        # to all frontends)
        proxy_next_upstream error;

    server {
        listen   80;
        server_name 127.0.0.1;

                location / {
            proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect false;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
                 proxy_pass http://frontends;
        }
```

Answer (score 210):

`ab` requires a trailing slash after the URL.

This should work:

```
ab -n 2000 -c 25 http://127.0.0.1/
```

Comment: You'd think that `ab` would be clever enough to either tell you this, or to fix it.  C'mon, that's barely even one line of code!  Cheers for this answer.

Comment: Exactly what the problem I had was, all hosts I was trying were minus the trailing slash - thanks!

Comment: Thank you! That's what I needed. As Luke said, you think it'd maybe handle this.